# How to change the code to find an approximation to the cube root of both negative and positive numbers?

Tags: python

So I'm entirely new to coding and I'm taking the MIT Openwarecourse to get started (and I'm using the book Introducing to Computation and Programming using Python)

Also since I'm new here I'm a bit afraid that my question is low quality so please point out if you think I should improve the manner on how I asks questions.

At 3.4 I'm given the code:

```
x = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
epsilon = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
low = -100
high = max(1.0, x)
ans = (high + low)/2.0
while abs(ans**2 -x) >= epsilon:
      print ("low = ", low, "High=", high, "ans=", ans)
      numGuesses += 1
      if ans**2 < x:
          low = ans
      else:
           high = ans
      ans = (high + low)/2.0
print ("numGuesses =", numGuesses)
print (ans, "Is close to square root of", x)
```

So what I tried to do first is understand each line of the code and what it exactly does. I've been given the hint: "Think about changing low to ensure that the answer lies within the region being searched.)

I've tried to change low to a negative number and I tried to add if low is less than 0, then low = -low like this:

```
x = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
epsilon = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
low = 0.0
if low < 0:
   low = -low 
high = max(1.0, x)
ans = (high + low)/2.0
while abs(ans**2 -x) >= epsilon:
      print ("low = ", low, "High=", high, "ans=", ans)
      numGuesses += 1
      if ans**2 < x:
          low = ans
      else:
           high = ans
      ans = (high + low)/2.0
print ("numGuesses =", numGuesses)
print (ans, "Is close to square root of", x)
```

However I'm probably taking a wrong approach...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your algorithm is a numerical search through [dichotomy method](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Dichotomy_method) applied to X^2-x=0, it converges (quite fast actually) towards the solution X=sqrt(x) as long as low is lower than the solution, and high is higher than the solution.

In your case x is always higher than sqrt(x) and 0 is always lower than sqrt(x).
The answer will always be in the region being searched,you can lower epsilon as much as you want. There is no point in changing the initialisation of low. If you lower it to negative values, it will only require a few more step, roughly log2(abs(low))

change

```
 ans**2
```

to

```
ans**3
```

and your algorithm converges to the cubic root of x.

The cubic root of negative numbers is not well defined, I guess what they mean is the cubic root of the absolute value, multiplied by -1. So (-3)^3 =-9
If x<0, replace x by abs(x), run the algorithm and return the solution multiplied by -1.

Comment: You can still use this method to find a square root of a negative number. Just find the square root of the absolute value of the number, then multiply the result by *i*. And of course negative numbers can have cube roots: -3 * -3 * -3 = -27.

Comment: No, to be precise, -3 is not the cubic root of -27, it is one of the three roots of X^3+27=0, this is why the denomination is sort of ill-posed. By convention square root usually refers to positive numbers, and is defined as the only positive root of the polynomial X²-x=0. It's just a matter of conventions.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close, to convert the program to find an approximation to the cube root of both negative and positive numbers you have to only change the range in which your algorithm is searching.

To find cube root of positive numbers:

```
x = 8
epsilon = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
high = max(1.0, x)
low = 0.0

ans = (high + low) / 2.0

while abs((pow(ans,3)- x)) >= epsilon:

    print("low ",low," ,high ",high," ans ",ans)
    numGuesses += 1

    if pow(ans,3) < x:
        low = ans

    else:
        high = ans

    ans = (high + low) /2.0

print("numguesses , = "+str(numGuesses))
print(str(ans)+"is close to square root of x "+ str(x))
```

The algorithm searches between low and high. 
Suppose a user enters a number say 8 implies high = 8 and low = 0.0 and then it performs the search and will output 2.0, if user enters a negative number say -8 then high = 1.0 and low = 0.0 which don't appear to be right,the correct limit should be i.e [-8,0) (cube root of a negative number is negative) "ignoring complex roots", in this case high = 0 and low = -8.
You can do it by a simple if else statement.

```
x = 8
epsilon = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
high = max(1.0, x)
low = 0.0



if x < 0:
 low = x
else:
 None   

ans = (high + low) / 2.0

while abs((pow(ans,3)- x)) >= epsilon:

    print("low ",low," ,high ",high," ans ",ans)
    numGuesses += 1

    if pow(ans,3) < x:
        low = ans

    else:
        high = ans

    ans = (high + low) /2.0
print("numguesses , = "+str(numGuesses))
print(str(ans)+"is close to square root of x "+ str(x))
```

I hope this is a beginner friendly answer.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem I used the min function and compared x to 1.0, then extracted the lowest value. I did this because it is the direct inverse of extracting the initial high value.

```
x = -25
epsilon = 0.01
num_guesses = 0
low = min(x, 1.0)
high = max(1.0, x)
ans = (high + low) / 2.0
while abs(ans**3 - x) >= epsilon:
    print('low =', low, 'high =', high, 'ans =', ans)
    num_guesses += 1
    if ans**3 < x:
        low = ans
    else:
        high = ans
    ans = (high + low) / 2.0
print('num guesses =', num_guesses)
print(ans, 'is close to cube root of', x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an alternative code that allows negatives of square, cube, etc roots while keeping the core of OP's code unchanged:

```
number = int(input('Number? '))
x = abs(number)
root = int(input('Root? '))
epsilon = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
low = 0.0
high = max(1.0, x)
ans = (high + low)/2.0

while abs(ans**root - x) >= epsilon:
    print('low =', low, 'high =', high, 'ans =', ans)
    numGuesses += 1
    if ans**root < x:
        low = ans
    else:
        high = ans
    ans = (high + low)/2.0

print('numGuesses =', numGuesses)

if number < 0:
    if root%2 == 1:
        ans = -ans
    else:
        ans = str(ans)+'i'

print(ans, 'is close to square root of', number)
```

It takes the input number as absolute and checks its signal after the calculation is performed. It also adds 'i' in case of even roots of negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
epsilon = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
low = -abs(x)
high = max(1.0, x)
ans = (high + low)/2.0
while abs(ans**2 -x) >= epsilon:
      print ("low = ", low, "High=", high, "ans=", ans)
      numGuesses += 1
      if ans**2 < x:
          low = ans
      else:
           high = ans
      ans = (high + low)/2.0
print ("numGuesses =", numGuesses)
print (ans, "Is close to square root of", x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(input('Enter the number you want to find the root of: '))
root = int(input('Enter the power number: '))
epsilon = 0.01
numGuesses = 0
low = 0.0
high = x    #note that u removed max()
guess = (high + low)/2.0    #note u changed ans to guess
while abs(abs(guess**root) - abs(x)) >= epsilon:
    print('low =', low, 'high =', high, 'ans =', guess)
    numGuesses += 1
    if abs(guess**root) < abs(x):
        low = guess
    else:
        high = guess
    guess = (high + low)/2.0
print('numGuesses =', numGuesses)
print(guess, 'is close to root of', x)
```

This works well and there are not a lot of changes from the OG code

Answer (score -2):

This:

```
low = 0.0
if low < 0:
low = -low
```

literally does nothing. You set `low = 0` and then check if it's less than 0 (which it isn't). Also, 0 is both positive and negative, so changing its sign does nothing.

I'm afraid I don't understand the problem entirely, but it looks like `high` and `low` are bounds within which you expect the square/cubed root to be?

If `x` is negative then you want to make sure your lower bound can encompass it. Maybe setting `low = x` would help?